# where can i find builtin gcc memcpy?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, built-in

In my program i use memcpy. Gcc generate code, that use __builtin___memcpy_chk. I  have downloaded gcc source code https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc and do grep -A 10 -R "__builtin___memcpy_chk" . but i can't find implementation __builtin___memcpy_chk. Where can i find implementation for this function?

Comment: What is it you want to do/find and why? It's not clear (to me) what you are actually trying to accomplish (or asking).

Comment: There isn't a source file with C code for memcpy in gcc that you could copy-paste elsewhere. It generates code directly. If you really want to look, it is somewhere in `gcc/config/i386/`. And glibc has a gazillion implementations of memcpy, if you didn't find one using SSE, you probably didn't look hard enough.

Comment: Are you looking for the `memcpy` source code **OR** the parsing / semantics for choosing the version of `memcpy`?

Comment: @JesperJuhl this site did not allow me to write a short question, I had to write a lot. I’m only interested in why I can’t find an implementation of the __builtin___memcpy_chk function

Comment: @DanyalMugutdinov simple answer from the functions name: It's built into the compiler there is no supporting library function the compiler generates the CPU instructions itself.

Comment: @RichardCritten It doesn’t scare me that this function is built into the compiler. I downloaded its source code and just wanted to see the place where this happens. Even if it is an assembly instruction or an intrinsics

Comment: If there is no such function and the compiler processes this place without calling the function - it's okay. But miracles do not happen, somewhere there is a place where assembler instructions appear instead of functions

Comment: _"... i have downloaded glibc source code..."_ you need the compiler source not the library source.

Comment: @RichardCritten I wrote below that I also downloaded the gcc source code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Builtins such as `__builtin___memcpy_chk` are not functions as such, so you may not find a "definition" for it.

GCC is a compiler. It implements the language. It reads your function definitions an emits a binary with instructions for the CPU. In this case it emits instructions for the CPU without reading a C or C++ source file. Instead, it directly manipulates the internal data structure that it uses to represent the program that it is compiling.

You may want to take a look at expand_builtin_memory_chk defined in [gcc/builtins.c](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/gcc/builtins.c#L10379) for what it does.

Comment: then what is it? How is this implemented if it is not a function? thanks for your reply

Comment: @DanyalMugutdinov GCC is a compiler. It implements the language. It reads your function definitions an emits a binary with instructions for the CPU. In this case it emits instructions for the CPU without reading a C or C++ source file. You can learn more by reading the function that I linked, and by following into functions that it calls. Forewarning: Compilers are complex beasts.